# Latest methods on using js to detect screen size to include php file

Tags: javascript

I've searched for latest info but can't find a full answer relevant to my situation and since I'm new to js and php I need a little more direction.

I created a site using Bootstrap and the popover section proved a problem on mobile (specifically Safari - it doesn't dismiss). I decided to use BS panels for mobile and used Bootstrap's .hidden-lg and .visible-sm classes to show that popovers are visible on desktops and panels are visible on mobile sizes. However the script clashed, as soon as both are in my html file, it won't load won't of them, eg. popovers won't work but panels does. I tried to place it differently, thinking maybe the order in my code matters. In the end I found that little sentence in BS docs that says "don't use data attributes from multiple plugins on the same element". I figured that means I can't use two types of plugins in my one page even though the two sections are not supposed to be displayed on the same page - it should load only one depending on the device size.

I searched for a method to use jquery to detect screen size to insert a php file. I created two php files (one for large screens, one for small, placed the popover and panel sections in each) I created my original index as a new index.php.

I can't tell where I went wrong because it's not working and I've made so many changes to the code to try and fix it that it's probably a mess right now anyway.

I tried another method: I found some old info to create m.domain.com which means you have to include link rel="alternate"... in desktop file and rel="canonical" in mobile to link to mobile_file.php

It loaded the correct files (though mobile is duplicating my footer for no apparent reason) but the js script is still not activating properly. Now mobile is loading panels but not dismissing it (and it worked for sure when I tested the single file before) and desktop popover is not opening up (meaning the js is not working) at all!

How can I use a simple method to say: if the screen size is this, use this file and if not, use that file. I'm sure this is possible with js but I just can't find a clear, easy to understand and follow method online. Clearly my js knowledge is lacking but a simple site is proving complicated in the final steps. All help would be appreciated because it's really hard to find updated info on this exact issue.

for more info: I used the Bootstrap html boilerplate which links this by default as script: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"

The panels would only work if I use src="js/jquery.min.js"

I know these two are the culprits because when I deleted the first then the panels would work and when I deleted the second the popovers would work but they will not work for both with either one of these. I don't know what to change to make it work.

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) might be a lot easier for you. Media queries seems to be what you are after

Comment: Since PHP files are included before the page is loaded in the browser, this can never be done with JS, since that is executed after the page is loaded. Apart from that, it would be very inefficient, since it would only load the correct file once. If the user were to scale the browser afterwards, nothing would change. I agree with @Icepickle, [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) are now the way to go, as far as screen size dependent styling goes.

Comment: Also, I might not exactly get what your problem is and what you want to achieve:) I'm sorry, it's a really long text without any proper code for us to check, so I may have misread some things.

Comment: @myfunkyside Wow you actually read the full text? :) Sorry Annefromallover, but it was a bit tl;dr; for me